# forEach is not finding the right user id when using sequelize findAll

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have a scenario in which a user like his post, and it will fills a heart, cool. If user 2 likes the same post, user 1 heart becomes unfilled.

there is a property `"likeByMe"` it is a boolean value.

It needs to check if the current user liked the post, or not.

Here are the scenarios

[image]

[image]

[image]

this is how im getting the posts, i'm using [setDataValue](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/instance/#setdatavaluekey-value)

**post.controller.js**

```
getPosts: async (req: any, res: Response) => {
  // use async/await here
  const posts = await models.Post.findAll({
    include: [
      { model: models.User, as: "author", attributes: ["username"] },
      {
        model: models.Likes
      }
    ],
    order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
    limit: 6
  });

  posts.forEach(post => {
    if (post.Likes.length === 0) {
      post.setDataValue("likedByMe", false);
    }
    post.Likes.forEach(like => {
      console.log(like.userId);
      if (like.userId === req.session.user.id) {
        post.setDataValue("likedByMe", true);
      } else {
        post.setDataValue("likedByMe", false);
      }
    });
  });

  return res.json(posts);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it right now but are you sure the `setDataValue` method saves the model instance after setting the values?

According to [the docs](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#instance-method-setDataValue) what it does is:

> Update the underlying data value

Which from my point of view what it means is it just updates the values under the `_data` private property of the instance but doesn't necessarily persists these updates in the database.

Maybe you should [`save()`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#instance-method-save) it after setting the `likedByMe` value.

Comment: I'm not sure if it does or not. but i will say that the property `likedByMe` is not apart of the posts table. setDataValue should just append a new property just to determine if user liked post or not, does that make sense ? so using save wouldn't be the solution i think as this property does not exist in the post table.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, i just removed the else statement and it works smoothly. I don't know why this works but it just does.

```
 posts.forEach(post => {
      if (post.Likes.length === 0) {
        post.setDataValue("likedByMe", false);
      }
      post.Likes.forEach(like => {
        console.log(like.userId);
        if (like.userId === req.session.user.id) {
          post.setDataValue("likedByMe", true);
        }
      });
    });
```